# Can't send headers after they are sent. File upload, async issue?

Tags: node.js, express, formidable

I am developing a multiple file upload feature using ajax, nodejs, express and the module formidable.

However I am sometimes getting the error `Can't set headers after they are sent.`, from the error stack trace, it's because of the line `return res.send({ status: 'success', files: files['upload']`

I tried to review what could make it be sent more than once, and I included a counter to make sure it would be fired one time once all files were uploaded, but the error still happens sometimes.

```
var express     = require('express'),
    router      = express.Router(),
    formidable  = require('formidable'),
    util        = require('util'),
    fs          = require('fs'),
    form        = new formidable.IncomingForm(),
    path        = require('path'),
    nodeHomeDir = path.dirname(require.main.filename);

form.type = 'multipart';
form.multiples = true;
form.maxFieldsSize = 52428800;
form.uploadDir = nodeHomeDir + '/tmp';
form.keepExtensions = true;

/* POST to /files to upload or delete files */
router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {

  form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
    if (!files['upload'][0]) return res.send({ status: 'fail', message: 'No files provided.' });

    req.on('aborted', function () {
      return res.send({ message: 'fail' });
    });

    var webinarID     = fields.webinarID,
        uploadDirName = nodeHomeDir + '/webinarFiles/' + webinarID,
        filesLength   = Object.keys(files['upload']).length,
        counter       = 0;

    if (!webinarID) return res.send({ status: 'fail', message: 'No webinar ID provided.' });

    if (!fs.existsSync(uploadDirName)) {
      fs.mkdirSync(uploadDirName);
    }

    for (file in files['upload']) {
      if (files['upload'][file] && files['upload'][file].path && files['upload'][file].name) {
        var stream = fs.createReadStream(files['upload'][file].path).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(uploadDirName + '/' + files['upload'][file].name));
        stream.on('finish', function () {
          counter++;
          if (counter === filesLength) {
            // deleteFilesFromFolder(nodeHomeDir + '/tmp');
            return res.send({ status: 'success', files: files['upload'] });
          }
        });
      }
    }

  });

});
```

Comment: Well, the array of keys you get back from `Object.keys()` is not necessarily the same length as the number of properties a `for ... in` loop will iterate through. If you wanted to be sure you're iterating only through the same keys, then iterate through the `Object.keys()` result directly with a plain `for` loop or with `.forEach()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try for this:

```
    var async = require('async');
    async.eachSeries(files['upload'], function(elem,asynccallback){
     if (files['upload'][file] && files['upload'][file].path && files['upload'][file].name) {
            var stream = fs.createReadStream(files['upload'][file].path).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(uploadDirName + '/' + files['upload'][file].name));
            stream.on('finish', function () {
              counter++;
              if (counter === filesLength) {
                // deleteFilesFromFolder(nodeHomeDir + '/tmp');
                return res.send({ status: 'success', files: files['upload'] });
              }
            });
          }
    asynccallback();
});
```